# Partial Internal Reflection

Tags: optics

What is partial internal reflection? Please elaborate with examples.

Why this phenomenon happens?
I searched on the internet but found nothing much.

Is this phenomenon involved in rainbow formation? 
I think so because in the formation of a rainbow, TIR can't be involved. The geometry of  a rain droplet doesn't allow it.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection  the second paragraph explains partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when light goes from medium A to medium B you get a reflection, if medium B is transparent the reflection is partial(the other part is the light transmitted to B).
Internal or external is arbitrary.
Air is a medium, so normal reflection from a glass window is just another case of partial reflection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Reflection_of_light